# Graphviz: How to go from .dot to a graph?

Tags: windows, graphviz, dot

I can't seem to figure this out. I have a .dot file, which is valid according to the syntax. How do I use Graphviz to convert this into an image?

(Note that I'm on Windows, not Linux)

Comment: For windows: dl the msi and install; Find `gvedit.exe` in your programs list; Open `.dot` file in question; Click running person on toolbar; Go to `graph -> settings`; change `Output file type` to file type of your liking and press ok..  It doesn't say anything, you just find the file in the same directory as your .dot file.

Answer (score 580, accepted):

Type

```
dot -Tps filename.dot -o outfile.ps
```

if you want to use the [dot](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/dot/) renderer. There are alternatives like [neato](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/neato/) and [twopi](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/neato/). If Graphiz isn't in your path, figure out where it is installed and run it from there.

You can change the [output format](https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/) by varying the value after `-T` and choosing an appropriate filename extension after `-o`.

If you're using Windows, check out the installed tool called [GVEdit](https://graphviz.org/docs/cli/gvedit/), it makes the whole process slightly easier.

Go look at the Graphviz site for more detail on how to use the tools: https://www.graphviz.org/documentation/

See section "Command Line Options" for output formatting for the dot command, for instance: https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf

Comment: somehow, the GVEdit preview always shows the image to be blank. When I try to save the image, nothing happens.

Comment: Is it possible to make GVEdit remember the size and location of the Layout windows? It drives me nuts that when I press F5 it always shrinks the size of the layout window back to default!

Comment: @PaulMcMillan, could you help me out with m problem here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477403/graphviz-dot-to-ps-issue`, my output is bounded to a fix page and some parts are out of the page

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to make GVEdit remember the windows. I agree the UX leaves something to be desired.

Comment: I made a terraform.dot file from a terraform graph command. I'm on windows. i did -o outfile.jpg and when I double click the jpg it locks up explorer. Tried gif also and got same issue.

Comment: This is wrong. You change the extension passed to the -T flag. The "extension" on the end of the filename is meaningless

Comment: You CANNOT change the output format by simply changing the file extension - you MUST specify the type with the -T option. Without the -T option, graphviz (which I think is great, BTW) will simply ignore the file extension, except, of course, your file will be named that way, but NOT be of the format you want.

Comment: The gvedit binary is not included in versions later than 2.38 due to copyright restrictions. A more polished interface is available in the similar [Msc-generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msc-generator). The layouts are not always identical.

Answer (score 281):

```
dot -Tps input.dot > output.eps
dot -Tpng input.dot > output.png
```

PostScript output seems always there. I am not sure if dot has PNG output by default. This may depend on how you have built it.

Comment: instead of using >, I suggest to use the « -o » parameter

Comment: Depending on what support your system has, you can export to all sorts of file formats. I found `dot -Tsvg input.dot > output.svg` quite useful.

Comment: Slightly easier, let dot chose the filename based on input filename and file type: dot -Tpng -O file.dot (will produce file.png)

Comment: Same command is working in macOS, via macports. :)

Answer (score 116):

> dot file.dot -Tpng -o image.png

This works on Windows and Linux. Graphviz must be installed.

Comment: Add Graphviz to Path

Comment: On OSX, you'll need to install Graphviz first using Homebrew: `brew install graphviz`

Comment: I can generate a png image with dot, but the background is white in color. I need a transparent background. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: 1. Install Graphviz from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html  
2. Add 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin' to your system variable PATH
3. Open cmd and go to the dir where you saved the .dot file
4. Use the command 'dot yourFile.dot -Tpng -o image.png'

Answer (score 60):

There are also the online viewers:

- http://www.webgraphviz.com/
- https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/
- https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js → emscripten → http://viz-js.com/
- [Using WASM port in ObservableHQ](https://observablehq.com/@gordonsmith/graphviz)
- https://sketchviz.com/new

Comment: I totally made Erdos and forgot about it ages ago. I had no idea how many people linked to it!

Comment: add a donate button ;)

Comment: I am trying to generate a graph for the C grammar from here http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html. But it's not successful. Is this grammar too big to be handled?

Answer (score 34):

Get the graphviz-2.24.msi [Graphviz.org](http://www.graphviz.org/). Then get [zgrviewer](http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html).

Zgrviewer requires java (probably 1.5+). You might have to set the paths to the Graphviz binaries in Zgrviewer's preferences.

File -> Open -> Open with dot -> SVG pipeline (standard) ...
Pick your .dot file.

You can zoom in, export, all kinds of fun stuff.

Comment: Lots of features, but an absolutely crazy interface design!

Answer (score 29):

This should combine a lot of answers.

```
# Convert dot to png via graphviz
dot -Tpng filename.dot -o filename.png

# Convert dot to svg via graphviz
dot -Tsvg filename.dot -o filename.svg

# Convert dot to eps via graphviz
dot -Tps filename.dot -o filename.eps
```

Keep in mind that on OSX (MAC), you need to install [homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install graphviz to be able to use the dot commands above.

```
brew install graphviz
```

It is also possible to install Graphviz (and use the commands above) through the package manager functionality of conda if you have Anaconda installed.

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the VS code and install the Graphviz extension or,

1. Install Graphviz from
   https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html
2. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` (or your_installation_path/ bin) to your system variable
   PATH
3. Open cmd and go to the dir where you saved the .dot file
4. Use the command `dot music-recommender.dot -Tpng -o image.png`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can also output your file in xdot format, then render it in a browser using canviz, a JavaScript library.

[Canviz on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/):

To see an example, there is a "Canviz Demo" link on the page above as of November 2, 2014.

Answer (score 8):

there is no requirement of any conversion.

We can simply use **xdot** command in Linux which is an Interactive viewer for Graphviz dot files.

ex: **xdot file.dot**

for more infor:https://github.com/rakhimov/cppdep/wiki/How-to-view-or-work-with-Graphviz-Dot-files

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was feeling dumb not getting my hands on the viewer version of dot ! :)

Answer (score 4):

$ dot -T pdf filename.dot > filename.pdf
This works on my Windows 10.

Comment: somehow PDF is the only one working for me

Answer (score 3):

For window user, Please run complete command to convert *.dot file to png:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe" -Tpng sampleTest.dot > sampletest.png.....
```

I have found a bug in solgraph that it is utilizing older version of solidity-parser that does not seem to be intelligent enough to capture new enhancement done for solidity programming language itself e.g. emit keyword for Event

Answer (score 3):

You can use a very good online tool for it. Here is the link
[dreampuf.github.io](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_0%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%3B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3Dlightgrey%3B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bstyle%3Dfilled%2Ccolor%3Dwhite%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a0%20-%3E%20a1%20-%3E%20a2%20-%3E%20a3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22process%20%231%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bstyle%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20b0%20-%3E%20b1%20-%3E%20b2%20-%3E%20b3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22process%20%232%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3Dblue%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20start%20-%3E%20a0%3B%0A%20%20start%20-%3E%20b0%3B%0A%20%20a1%20-%3E%20b3%3B%0A%20%20b2%20-%3E%20a3%3B%0A%20%20a3%20-%3E%20a0%3B%0A%20%20a3%20-%3E%20end%3B%0A%20%20b3%20-%3E%20end%3B%0A%0A%20%20start%20%5Bshape%3DMdiamond%5D%3B%0A%20%20end%20%5Bshape%3DMsquare%5D%3B%0A%7D)
Just replace the code inside editer with your code.