# GraphViz: how to get UTF-8 AND external PostScript procedures?

Tags: utf-8, graphviz, postscript

**Goal**: draw a flowchart which contains non-Latin1 symbols.

**Problem**: GraphViz does not provide all node shapes necessary for drawing a flowchart (e.g. "Document", "Predefined Process" etc). Fortunately, a person named Jason Brazile created a [nice library](http://jbrazile.blogspot.ru/2012/04/postscript-flowchart-symbols-for.html) of missing shapes. However, it works only when using the PostScript driver (`dot -Tps`).

There are two basic PostScript drivers in GraphViz: built-in driver which does not support Unicode, and Cairo which does, but apparently does not support external PostScript procedures (the user-defined PS shapes are absent in the resulting layout).

**Question**: How do I use UTF-8 labels *and* flowchart shapes at the same time?

Comment: This question does not seem to be about programming, as defined in the [help]. Hence, I am voting to close this question. It may be more suitable on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or one of our other sister sites.

Comment: @tripleee: excuse me, I thought that since questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1494492/1002951) are OK here then I can post mine as well.

Comment: I agree that the question you link to is problematic, too. Very fundamental questions like "how do I compile" are borderline, but yours does not seem to have any programming component at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the GraphViz developers about this and looks like the answer is that there is no way to do that:

> We looked at this problem years ago. The native graphviz -Tps
>   Postscript driver does not have any custom font loading capabilites. 
>   As mentioned here:   http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-5.html
>   rendering utf-8 fonts in Postscript is a do-it-yourself job. It would
>   probably take weeks or months of work, but if you want to try to make
>   this modification to graphviz, it might be possible to appropriate
>   code from one of the other tools mentioned in that website.  (Make
>   sure it is non-GPL code, otherwise it can't be distributed!)
>
> Another option would be to modify the cairopango driver to render text
>   on top of a user shape after it is loaded. (Do we not already support
>   this? It seems obvious.) Then either find a way to render external
>   graphviz PS shapes after they are loaded and copy the rendered images
>   into the cairopango canvas (hey we already import ghostscript into
>   graphviz) or convert the custom PS shapes externally into images that
>   can be loaded by the cairopango driver.  This might not take as much
>   time.
>
> Either way, it will take an expert C programmer.
>
> Probably none of us have much time to work on this (our time would be
>   better used trying to get funding to support the project in a more
>   general way, but we all have other jobs now) but you could offer a
>   bounty on bountysource and see what happens....