# How to display decision tree plot using export_graphviz

Tags: export, graphviz, decision-tree, dot

**NEWBIE**

using microsoft version 10, python 3.5.2, dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (correctly installed)

trying to use export_graphviz to visualize a decision tree.
think it is pretty close, just can't do the last step.

here is the sample code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file='tree.dot')
```

`

the 'tree.dot' file is output.  when double clicked, it calls up microsoft word and display the following text.

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box] ;
0 [label="X[2] <= 2.45\ngini = 0.6667\nsamples = 150\nvalue = [50, 50, 50]"] ;
1 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 50\nvalue = [50, 0, 0]"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="X[3] <= 1.75\ngini = 0.5\nsamples = 100\nvalue = [0, 50, 50]"] ;
0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
3 [label="X[2] <= 4.95\ngini = 0.168\nsamples = 54\nvalue = [0, 49, 5]"] ;
2 -> 3 ;
4 [label="X[3] <= 1.65\ngini = 0.0408\nsamples = 48\nvalue = [0, 47, 1]"] ;
3 -> 4 ;
5 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 47\nvalue = [0, 47, 0]"] ;
4 -> 5 ;
6 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 1\nvalue = [0, 0, 1]"] ;
4 -> 6 ;
7 [label="X[3] <= 1.55\ngini = 0.4444\nsamples = 6\nvalue = [0, 2, 4]"] ;
3 -> 7 ;
8 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 3\nvalue = [0, 0, 3]"] ;
7 -> 8 ;
9 [label="X[0] <= 6.95\ngini = 0.4444\nsamples = 3\nvalue = [0, 2, 1]"] ;
7 -> 9 ;
10 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 2\nvalue = [0, 2, 0]"] ;
9 -> 10 ;
11 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 1\nvalue = [0, 0, 1]"] ;
9 -> 11 ;
12 [label="X[2] <= 4.85\ngini = 0.0425\nsamples = 46\nvalue = [0, 1, 45]"] ;
2 -> 12 ;
13 [label="X[1] <= 3.1\ngini = 0.4444\nsamples = 3\nvalue = [0, 1, 2]"] ;
12 -> 13 ;
14 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 2\nvalue = [0, 0, 2]"] ;
13 -> 14 ;
15 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 1\nvalue = [0, 1, 0]"] ;
13 -> 15 ;
16 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 43\nvalue = [0, 0, 43]"] ;
12 -> 16 ;
}
```

this example code works properly

> [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-iris-py ][1]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer worked great for me!  thanks ashley!

For windows: dl the msi and install; Find gvedit.exe in your programs list; Open .dot file in question; Click running person on toolbar; Go to graph -> settings; change Output file type to file type of your liking and press ok.. It doesn't say anything, you just find the file in the same directory as your .dot file. – ashley Mar 26 '15 at 9:15

[Graphviz: How to go from .dot to a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494492/graphviz-how-to-go-from-dot-to-a-graph)