# How do I get microsoft word or pycharm to read dot files as a graphic instead of code

Tags: ms-word, dot

When I open my .dot file with microsoft word or pycharm it shows me the code and that the code is error free but doesnt display the intended graphic.

I have extensively searched on google for a solution but google insists that microsoft word comes with the ability to read .dot files (which it seems to be able to read the code but not display the graphic). I downloaded the pycharm .dot reading plug-in and now pycharm can read the code and it says that the code is error free, but again it does not display the graphic.

I am unsure what code is necessary so I am just giving the whole thing.

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box, style="filled, rounded", color="black", fontname=helvetica] ;
edge [fontname=helvetica] ;
0 [label="failures <= 0.5\nsamples = 100.0%\nvalue = [0.502, 0.498]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e5813902"] ;
1 [label="higher_no <= 0.5\nsamples = 84.8%\nvalue = [0.422, 0.578]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de545"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="school_GP <= 0.5\nsamples = 79.2%\nvalue = [0.386, 0.614]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de55e"] ;
1 -> 2 ;
3 [label="absences <= 1.5\nsamples = 23.0%\nvalue = [0.574, 0.426]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e5813942"] ;
2 -> 3 ;
4 [label="freetime <= 4.5\nsamples = 12.4%\nvalue = [0.419, 0.581]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de547"] ;
3 -> 4 ;
5 [label="samples = 11.6%\nvalue = [0.379, 0.621]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de563"] ;
4 -> 5 ;
6 [label="samples = 0.8%\nvalue = [1.0, 0.0]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139ff"] ;
4 -> 6 ;
7 [label="health <= 1.5\nsamples = 10.6%\nvalue = [0.755, 0.245]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139ac"] ;
3 -> 7 ;
8 [label="samples = 2.2%\nvalue = [0.455, 0.545]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de52a"] ;
7 -> 8 ;
9 [label="samples = 8.4%\nvalue = [0.833, 0.167]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139cc"] ;
7 -> 9 ;
10 [label="Walc <= 3.5\nsamples = 56.2%\nvalue = [0.31, 0.69]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de58d"] ;
2 -> 10 ;
11 [label="Medu <= 3.5\nsamples = 46.4%\nvalue = [0.263, 0.737]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de5a4"] ;
10 -> 11 ;
12 [label="samples = 29.4%\nvalue = [0.333, 0.667]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de57f"] ;
11 -> 12 ;
13 [label="samples = 17.0%\nvalue = [0.141, 0.859]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de5d5"] ;
11 -> 13 ;
14 [label="sex_M <= 0.5\nsamples = 9.8%\nvalue = [0.531, 0.469]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e581391d"] ;
10 -> 14 ;
15 [label="samples = 3.0%\nvalue = [0.267, 0.733]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de5a2"] ;
14 -> 15 ;
16 [label="samples = 6.8%\nvalue = [0.647, 0.353]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e5813974"] ;
14 -> 16 ;
17 [label="reason_course <= 0.5\nsamples = 5.6%\nvalue = [0.929, 0.071]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139eb"] ;
1 -> 17 ;
18 [label="health <= 3.5\nsamples = 2.6%\nvalue = [0.846, 0.154]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139d1"] ;
17 -> 18 ;
19 [label="samples = 1.4%\nvalue = [1.0, 0.0]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139ff"] ;
18 -> 19 ;
20 [label="reason_home <= 0.5\nsamples = 1.2%\nvalue = [0.667, 0.333]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e581397f"] ;
18 -> 20 ;
21 [label="samples = 0.6%\nvalue = [0.333, 0.667]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de57f"] ;
20 -> 21 ;
22 [label="samples = 0.6%\nvalue = [1.0, 0.0]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139ff"] ;
20 -> 22 ;
23 [label="samples = 3.0%\nvalue = [1.0, 0.0]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139ff"] ;
17 -> 23 ;
24 [label="Fjob_teacher <= 0.5\nsamples = 15.2%\nvalue = [0.947, 0.053]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139f1"] ;
0 -> 24 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
25 [label="Fjob_health <= 0.5\nsamples = 15.0%\nvalue = [0.96, 0.04]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139f4"] ;
24 -> 25 ;
26 [label="freetime <= 1.5\nsamples = 14.8%\nvalue = [0.973, 0.027]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139f8"] ;
25 -> 26 ;
27 [label="Mjob_at_home <= 0.5\nsamples = 0.6%\nvalue = [0.667, 0.333]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e581397f"] ;
26 -> 27 ;
28 [label="samples = 0.2%\nvalue = [0.0, 1.0]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de5ff"] ;
27 -> 28 ;
29 [label="samples = 0.4%\nvalue = [1.0, 0.0]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139ff"] ;
27 -> 29 ;
30 [label="age <= 16.5\nsamples = 14.2%\nvalue = [0.986, 0.014]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139fb"] ;
26 -> 30 ;
31 [label="samples = 2.4%\nvalue = [0.917, 0.083]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139e8"] ;
30 -> 31 ;
32 [label="samples = 11.8%\nvalue = [1.0, 0.0]\nclass = fail", fillcolor="#e58139ff"] ;
30 -> 32 ;
33 [label="samples = 0.2%\nvalue = [0.0, 1.0]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de5ff"] ;
25 -> 33 ;
34 [label="samples = 0.2%\nvalue = [0.0, 1.0]\nclass = pass", fillcolor="#399de5ff"] ;
24 -> 34 ;
}
```

I expect the above code to display a color-coded decision tree. Instead microsoft word, pycharm, and jupyter notebook are all returning the code.

Answer (score 2):

A GraphViz `.dot` file is **not** an image file. It rather contains a logical description of some content (nodes and edges), along with some graphical clues how to display them (e.g. color, font sizes). The exact positions of each element are not defined in the `.dot` file at all. Calculating these positions, and rendering actual image files, is left to a layout engine, such as `dot`, or derived Javascript libraries (e.g. `viz.js`).

Almost no application can display GraphViz `.dot` files directly.

The confusion probably comes from a conflicting naming convention:

1. **GraphViz** .dot file (what we are talking about here)
2. **Microsoft** .dot file (what Word is expecting and Google might refer to)

A Microsoft .do**t** file is a template for a Microsoft Word (.do**c**) file.

In order to present your desired graphic, you need to run your .dot file through a layout engine to produce e.g. an `.svg` or `.png` file.

You can do this manually on your local PC or online (e.g. [https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20Tree%20%7B%0Anode%20%5Bshape%3Dbox%2C%20style%3D%22filled%2C%20rounded%22%2C%20color%3D%22black%22%2C%20fontname%3Dhelvetica%5D%20%3B%0Aedge%20%5Bfontname%3Dhelvetica%5D%20%3B%0A0%20%5Blabel%3D%22failures%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%20100.0%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.502%2C%200.498%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e5813902%22%5D%20%3B%0A1%20%5Blabel%3D%22higher_no%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2084.8%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.422%2C%200.578%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de545%22%5D%20%3B%0A0%20-%3E%201%20%5Blabeldistance%3D2.5%2C%20labelangle%3D45%2C%20headlabel%3D%22True%22%5D%20%3B%0A2%20%5Blabel%3D%22school_GP%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2079.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.386%2C%200.614%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de55e%22%5D%20%3B%0A1%20-%3E%202%20%3B%0A3%20%5Blabel%3D%22absences%20%3C%3D%201.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2023.0%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.574%2C%200.426%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e5813942%22%5D%20%3B%0A2%20-%3E%203%20%3B%0A4%20%5Blabel%3D%22freetime%20%3C%3D%204.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2012.4%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.419%2C%200.581%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de547%22%5D%20%3B%0A3%20-%3E%204%20%3B%0A5%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%2011.6%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.379%2C%200.621%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de563%22%5D%20%3B%0A4%20-%3E%205%20%3B%0A6%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%200.8%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B1.0%2C%200.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A4%20-%3E%206%20%3B%0A7%20%5Blabel%3D%22health%20%3C%3D%201.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2010.6%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.755%2C%200.245%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139ac%22%5D%20%3B%0A3%20-%3E%207%20%3B%0A8%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%202.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.455%2C%200.545%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de52a%22%5D%20%3B%0A7%20-%3E%208%20%3B%0A9%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%208.4%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.833%2C%200.167%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139cc%22%5D%20%3B%0A7%20-%3E%209%20%3B%0A10%20%5Blabel%3D%22Walc%20%3C%3D%203.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2056.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.31%2C%200.69%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de58d%22%5D%20%3B%0A2%20-%3E%2010%20%3B%0A11%20%5Blabel%3D%22Medu%20%3C%3D%203.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2046.4%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.263%2C%200.737%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de5a4%22%5D%20%3B%0A10%20-%3E%2011%20%3B%0A12%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%2029.4%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.333%2C%200.667%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de57f%22%5D%20%3B%0A11%20-%3E%2012%20%3B%0A13%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%2017.0%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.141%2C%200.859%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de5d5%22%5D%20%3B%0A11%20-%3E%2013%20%3B%0A14%20%5Blabel%3D%22sex_M%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%209.8%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.531%2C%200.469%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e581391d%22%5D%20%3B%0A10%20-%3E%2014%20%3B%0A15%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%203.0%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.267%2C%200.733%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de5a2%22%5D%20%3B%0A14%20-%3E%2015%20%3B%0A16%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%206.8%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.647%2C%200.353%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e5813974%22%5D%20%3B%0A14%20-%3E%2016%20%3B%0A17%20%5Blabel%3D%22reason_course%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%205.6%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.929%2C%200.071%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139eb%22%5D%20%3B%0A1%20-%3E%2017%20%3B%0A18%20%5Blabel%3D%22health%20%3C%3D%203.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%202.6%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.846%2C%200.154%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139d1%22%5D%20%3B%0A17%20-%3E%2018%20%3B%0A19%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%201.4%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B1.0%2C%200.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A18%20-%3E%2019%20%3B%0A20%20%5Blabel%3D%22reason_home%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%201.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.667%2C%200.333%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e581397f%22%5D%20%3B%0A18%20-%3E%2020%20%3B%0A21%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%200.6%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.333%2C%200.667%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de57f%22%5D%20%3B%0A20%20-%3E%2021%20%3B%0A22%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%200.6%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B1.0%2C%200.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A20%20-%3E%2022%20%3B%0A23%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%203.0%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B1.0%2C%200.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A17%20-%3E%2023%20%3B%0A24%20%5Blabel%3D%22Fjob_teacher%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2015.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.947%2C%200.053%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139f1%22%5D%20%3B%0A0%20-%3E%2024%20%5Blabeldistance%3D2.5%2C%20labelangle%3D-45%2C%20headlabel%3D%22False%22%5D%20%3B%0A25%20%5Blabel%3D%22Fjob_health%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2015.0%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.96%2C%200.04%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139f4%22%5D%20%3B%0A24%20-%3E%2025%20%3B%0A26%20%5Blabel%3D%22freetime%20%3C%3D%201.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2014.8%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.973%2C%200.027%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139f8%22%5D%20%3B%0A25%20-%3E%2026%20%3B%0A27%20%5Blabel%3D%22Mjob_at_home%20%3C%3D%200.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%200.6%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.667%2C%200.333%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e581397f%22%5D%20%3B%0A26%20-%3E%2027%20%3B%0A28%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%200.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.0%2C%201.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de5ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A27%20-%3E%2028%20%3B%0A29%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%200.4%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B1.0%2C%200.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A27%20-%3E%2029%20%3B%0A30%20%5Blabel%3D%22age%20%3C%3D%2016.5%5Cnsamples%20%3D%2014.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.986%2C%200.014%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139fb%22%5D%20%3B%0A26%20-%3E%2030%20%3B%0A31%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%202.4%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.917%2C%200.083%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139e8%22%5D%20%3B%0A30%20-%3E%2031%20%3B%0A32%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%2011.8%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B1.0%2C%200.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20fail%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23e58139ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A30%20-%3E%2032%20%3B%0A33%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%200.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.0%2C%201.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de5ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A25%20-%3E%2033%20%3B%0A34%20%5Blabel%3D%22samples%20%3D%200.2%25%5Cnvalue%20%3D%20%5B0.0%2C%201.0%5D%5Cnclass%20%3D%20pass%22%2C%20fillcolor%3D%22%23399de5ff%22%5D%20%3B%0A24%20-%3E%2034%20%3B%0A%7D%0A) ), then save the resulting image.

You can present both .svg and .png images in Word (Insert / Image).

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get the .dot file to open properly using GVEdit (graphviz text editor). Here is a link to a post that answers my question. [Graphviz: How to go from .dot to a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494492/graphviz-how-to-go-from-dot-to-a-graph)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to open dot file directly from word as it will give an error. Open Ms-word first then locate the dot file which you want to open.

Comment: I have just tried opening word first and got the same results. (I can also open microsoft word by clicking on the document but it seems to open it as a regular microsoft word document). When I try using File Viewer Plus I am getting an error but it says that there is something wrong with the application so maybe there is just something wrong with my .dot file itself?

Comment: except the pycharm .dot plug-in isnt seeing any errors in the code.