# Can you make Nextflow DAG visualisation beautiful?

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, nextflow

Nextflow allows to efficiently make complex pipelines. Some people understand things only visually, so it's important to make a good graphical representation. Way to do so in nextflow is by -with-dag command:

```
nextflow run <script-name> -with-dag flowchart.png
```

However, output looks bad and doesn't have any professional vibe to it:

[image]

**I wonder if there are any ways to improve it**, like getting source code and uploading on some different visualisation programms. Anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use DOT format output and Graphviz

**tl;dr:** Use the `-with-dag` flag without a filename and use Graphviz to render the resulting `dag.dot` file.

[Graphvis](http://%20https://graphviz.org/) is a software package built specifically for visualizing these sorts of graphs.  Nextflow's [DAG visualization option](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/tracing.html#dag-visualisation) will output a [DOT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) representation by default.  Instead of specifying `-with-dag flowchart.png` use the naked flag `-with-dag` to emit `dag.dot` or specify the filename of your choice with the `.dot` extension.  Rendering a dot file to a visualization is the subject of [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494492/graphviz-how-to-go-from-dot-to-a-graph) and [documentation](https://graphviz.org/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from GcL's solution that allows you to use whatever solution you want based on the dot file, Nextflow currently supports an interactive HTML/JS DAG. You can quickly view an example of how it looks like with the command below:

```
nextflow run -resume nextflow-io/rnaseq-nf -r dev -with-dag dag.html
```

PS: If you don't have Docker running in your machine, set *-without-docker*, but this will require you to have some dependencies installed such as fastqc. Having the information within the dot file allows you to use things like [dagviz](https://wimyedema.github.io/dagviz/index.html) which, in my opinion, is pretty neat.